# Best Data historisation method

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

We are developing a domotic software that historizes a lot of data. All data are stored in a database using sqlite 3 engine.

For example, we acquire temperature every 30 seconds. So there is 2880 lines for one day of acquisition.

When our web interface ask to the server daily data to chart them, there is no problem.
But when our web interface ask for 6 months of data, our server take a lot of time to build the answer even using index (around 520 000 lines).

We search a method that could improve speed returning only useful information. For example all data when we ask daily graph but a mean of daily data when asking for a month, ...

We can change database structure as we want (add columns, add tables,)

Have you some idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to match the "summary table design"

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/identifying-summary-tables-data-warehouse-20822

The aim is to create (a) summary table(s) which keep data that match a specific criteria.

For example, you could create one table which summarize all your data for one day.
So it could give the mean value per day, with a fast query.